# How to solve "Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier"?

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, logic

I am creating application where I need to call SQL procedure.

**The parameter where I get the error is last , that is fifteenth parameter, contactID .. First five parameters are also unique identifiers but they set properly..only the last one that is, contactID throws exception while trying to set it as procedure parameter.**

Here is my Java code :

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "null" })
    @Override
    public JSONObject saveProductData(ProductsDataToSaveDTO ProductsDataToSaveDTO) throws SQLException {
        String output = "";
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement sta = null;
        String errorClassAndMethod = getErrorContainingClassAndMethod();
        JSONObject jsonOutput = new JSONObject();
        try {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            String json = gson.toJson(ProductsDataToSaveDTO);
            org.json.JSONObject jsonInput = new org.json.JSONObject(json);
            conn = createConnection(jsonInput);
            sta = conn.createStatement();

            String SPsql = "{call SP_InsertUpdateAdvisoryBoxProductDetails (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(SPsql);
            System.out.println(jsonInput);
            org.json.JSONArray productsList = (org.json.JSONArray) jsonInput.get("productsList");

                ps.setString(1, ProductsDataToSaveDTO.getClientId());
                ps.setString(2, ProductsDataToSaveDTO.getDivisionId());
                ps.setString(3, ProductsDataToSaveDTO.getClientRoleId());
                ps.setString(4, ProductsDataToSaveDTO.getUserID());
                ps.setString(5, ProductsDataToSaveDTO.getUserLoginDetailId());

                for (ProductsList productsListBO : ProductsDataToSaveDTO.getProductsList()) {

                    if (productsListBO.getProductCategory().equalsIgnoreCase("AOV")) {

                    ps.setString(6, productsListBO.getProductSituation());
                    String output2 = productsListBO.getProductSituation();
                    ps.setString(7, productsListBO.getProductCategory());
                    ps.setString(8, productsListBO.getProductSubcategory());
                    ps.setString(9, productsListBO.getProviderName());
                    ps.setString(10, productsListBO.getProductName());
                    ps.setString(11, productsListBO.getServiceProvider());
                    ps.setString(12, productsListBO.getPolicyNumber());
                    ps.setString(13,productsListBO.getProductClosed());
                    ps.setString(14, productsListBO.getNameFirstInsured());
                    ps.setString(15, productsListBO.getContactID());
                    }
                    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        output = rs.getString(1);
                        jsonOutput.put("status", output);
                    }
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            output = e.toString();
            e.printStackTrace();
            String errorMessageAndClassWithMethod = getErrorContainingClassAndMethod();
            throw new SpringAppRuntimeException(errorMessageAndClassWithMethod + e.toString());
        } finally {
            if (sta != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        }
        return jsonOutput;
    }
```

when I run my service, I get the error as , 
**"Application runtime exception occurred. [Error in ClassName.saveProductData : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.]"**

What changes I should make in the code to run it successfully?

Comment: For which variable it's giving the error.

Comment: Hi, it's throwing exception while setting this parameter : 
" ps.setString(15, productsListBO.getContactID());"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on your comment, I am adding it as answer

1) `ps.setString(15, productsListBO.getContactID());"`

2) Check 15th argument of your procedure `SP_InsertUpdateAdvisoryBoxProductDetails` is `@ProductSituation NVARCHAR(10)`

3) Is that really an identifier field and does the varchar matches the length of contactID? change that 10 to say 100 and test.

4) I also think your order of setting values in parameter (based on method names) and the order in which your procedure takes parameter is different. Go through it and correct that as well

Comment: Did few changes as per your suggestions and it worked..thanks.